# jvm hung while executing a query

Tags: java, database, multithreading, jvm

A query execution, like simply a select statement is taking 12 minutes and because of which entire JVM is hanging occasionaly like once in 15 day in one environment.

I have tried to simulate that by using Thread.sleep(600000) before the execution, but it is executing properly after 12 mins and the JVM is working fine. I would do a query timeout for that environment, but the question is why a single thread hang causing entire JVM to hang.

App server I am using is websphere and there is no lock held by that execution of query.

The message in other threads is:
at java/lang/Object.wait(Native Method)

Comment: what is your query returning after 12 minutes? how many rows? how many columns?

Comment: It is some select query for viewing the transaction reports,having 15 columns and 2 lakh rows,but the question here is why that thread doing query execution is causing other threads to wait,resulting in hang?

Comment: I'd say most likely db locks from the long query blocking everything else, but that's just guessing

Comment: Does the select statment executing for 12 mins holds any lock on the same table or other tables under the same schema?I think select statements hold shared lock only.